# How to change port number of Apache server in ubuntu

Tags: apache

I want to change my port number 80 to some other number of my Apache server . how it possible in ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Change your virtal host on any OS, ubuntu path is something like /etc/apache2/apache2 config or something.

```
#Virtual host for YOURSITE
<VirtualHost *:4343>  
        ServerAdmin john.doe@jd.com
        ServerName webpage.dev #same as in your /etc/hosts file
        DocumentRoot /var/www/yoursite
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        <Directory /var/www/yoursite>
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/yoursite_error.log 
        #CustomLog /var/log/apache2/customLog.log  #for ubuntu
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this will help you, you should read about apache coinfiguration...

Here's a great link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-apache-web-server-on-an-ubuntu-or-debian-vps

Answer (score 0):

You can create a virtual host configuration file  in /etc/apache2/sites-available

Example :--

```
  <VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

. . .

and you have to change Listen port on /etc/apache2/ports.conf

EX:--
Listen 8080